# Very Basic Backbone.js issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm sure this is obvious but I am new to backbone.js and have wasted a lot of time on it.  I'm trying to set up a very simple example with Backbone where this.name is a persons name and the program alerts 'hi' when the name is changed.  However when I run the code below I get the error

Object function (){a.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'get'

```
this.name = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      this.bind('change', function() {alert('hi')});
    },
    defaults : {
      name: 'bob'
    }

  });

console.log(this.name.get('name'));
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, this is driving me crazy :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.name` hasn't been instantiated yet. Try this instead:

```
this.nameModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.bind('change', function() {alert('hi')});
  },
  defaults : {
    name: 'bob'
  }
});

// instantiate the model
this.name = new this.nameModel();
console.log(this.name.get('name'));
```

Comment: thanks so much, I misunderstood how extends works I think, feeling very dumb lol :)